# Load multiple images with incremental urls

Tags: python

i have 1 problem i would like everyone to help. I need to download image files on 1 website, links https://acb.xyz.0001.jpg and the following files it similarly only change the number of extensions to https://acb.xyz.0002.jpg. Is there a way to use python to save those images. I tried to manually save each photo but it was too much.

Comment: That can surely be achieved with Python, but before anyone here start trying to help you, it is needed that you show us your coding attempt on solving the problem.

Comment: What is the real URL?

Comment: A quick search for "download image python" https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/download-image-python/. For url generation, `url = f"https://acb.xyz.{idx:04d}.jpg"`

Comment: @TBFTTH - All of your links give a 404 error.

Comment: I'm sorry but the link of the first image is like this

Comment: You aren't going to have much luck automating the downloads in any language if every link results in 404. A 404 in the browser is also going to be a 404 when you make the request programmatically.

Comment: You haven't written any code for us to fix. This isn't a code writing service. Also, you basically just want to steal the document. I don't see a download button, and you intend to invent one. I can't help you do that. Why can't you just read it online? The whole book is right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have already know how many image you need to download you can use this code.

```py
import requests
# Url to download content from 
URL = "http://thuvien.hmu.edu.vn/pages/cms/TempDir/books/01419632-d344-4a8e-9f53-4e40be647c3a/2022/09/13/202209071405-e0309899-377b-43d1-9033-972aa96844b5/FullPreview/"
# suffix 000001.jpg
# :05d
# Maximum number of image to download
max_image_size =3

# function for writing requests to png files
def dumpfile(n, m):
    f = open(n, 'wb')
    f.write(m)
    f.close()

# Itearate over the image urls and call dumpfile function
for i in range(1,max_image_size):
    suffix = str(f'{i:06d}')
    target=URL+ suffix+'.jpg'# added number of png
    print(target)
    response = requests.get(target)
    
    fileName=str(i)+'.jpg'
    dumpfile(fileName,response.content)
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't seem to work, can you run it for me, here's the link to the first photo

Comment: Problem is leading zeros I will update my code for your URL

Comment: Thank you very much for this enthusiasm

Comment: No problem mate, This one works you can mark as answer...

Comment: I am very much indebted to you, it has worked already